# proportions of a perspective-deformed rectangle

Tags: image-processing, geometry, computer-vision, reverseprojection, projective-geometry

Given a 2d picture of a rectangle distorted by perspective:

[image]

I know that the shape was originally a rectangle, but I do not know its original size.

If I know the pixel coordinates of the corners in this picture, how can I calculate the original proportions, i.e. the quotient ( width / height ) of the rectangle?

(background: the goal is to automatically undistort photos of rectangular documents, edge detection will probably be done with hough transform)

## UPDATE:

There has been some discussion on whether it is possible at all to determine the width:height ratio with the information given. My naive thought was that it must be possible, since I can think of no way to project for example a 1:4 rectangle onto the quadrangle depicted above. The ratio appears clearly close to 1:1, so there should be a way to determine it mathematically. I have however no proof for this beyond my intuitive guess.

I have not yet fully understood the arguments presented below, but I think there must be some implicit assumption that we are missing here and that is interpreted differently.

However, after hours of searching, I have finally found some papers relevant to the problem.
I am struggling to understand the math used in there, so far without success. Particularly the first paper seems to discuss exactly what I wanted to do, unfortunately without code examples and very dense math.

- Zhengyou Zhang , Li-Wei He, "Whiteboard scanning and image enhancement"
  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/papers/tr03-39.pdf p.11

  > "Because of the perspective distortion, the image of a rectangle appears to be a quadrangle. However, since we know that it is a rectangle in space, we are able to estimate both the camera’s focal length and the rectangle’s aspect ratio."
- ROBERT M. HARALICK "Determining camera parameters from the perspective projection of a rectangle"
  http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=87146

  > "we show how to use the 2D perspective projection of a rectangle of unknown size and position in 3D space to determine the camera look angle parameters relative to the plans of the rectangle."

Comment: p.s.
just to be clear: the width and height itself are of course indeterminable with the information given, I am looking for the the quotient of width / height

Comment: I've updated my answer, the conclusion is that the quotient width/height is also indeterminable with the information given.

Comment: I've updated mine too. If you know the image center, then the problem has actually one solution.  See the diagrams I added.

Comment: Your friend here is projective geometry.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is my attempt at answering my question after reading the paper

- Zhengyou Zhang , Li-Wei He,
  "Whiteboard scanning and image enhancement" http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/papers/tr03-39.pdf

I manipulated the equations for some time in SAGE, and came up with this pseudo-code in c-style:

```
// in case it matters: licensed under GPLv2 or later
// legend:
// sqr(x)  = x*x
// sqrt(x) = square root of x

// let m1x,m1y ... m4x,m4y be the (x,y) pixel coordinates
// of the 4 corners of the detected quadrangle
// i.e. (m1x, m1y) are the cordinates of the first corner, 
// (m2x, m2y) of the second corner and so on.
// let u0, v0 be the pixel coordinates of the principal point of the image
// for a normal camera this will be the center of the image, 
// i.e. u0=IMAGEWIDTH/2; v0 =IMAGEHEIGHT/2
// This assumption does not hold if the image has been cropped asymmetrically

// first, transform the image so the principal point is at (0,0)
// this makes the following equations much easier
m1x = m1x - u0;
m1y = m1y - v0;
m2x = m2x - u0;
m2y = m2y - v0;
m3x = m3x - u0;
m3y = m3y - v0;
m4x = m4x - u0;
m4y = m4y - v0;


// temporary variables k2, k3
double k2 = ((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x) /
            ((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) ;

double k3 = ((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x) / 
            ((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) ;

// f_squared is the focal length of the camera, squared
// if k2==1 OR k3==1 then this equation is not solvable
// if the focal length is known, then this equation is not needed
// in that case assign f_squared= sqr(focal_length)
double f_squared = 
    -((k3*m3y - m1y)*(k2*m2y - m1y) + (k3*m3x - m1x)*(k2*m2x - m1x)) / 
                      ((k3 - 1)*(k2 - 1)) ;

//The width/height ratio of the original rectangle
double whRatio = sqrt( 
    (sqr(k2 - 1) + sqr(k2*m2y - m1y)/f_squared + sqr(k2*m2x - m1x)/f_squared) /
    (sqr(k3 - 1) + sqr(k3*m3y - m1y)/f_squared + sqr(k3*m3x - m1x)/f_squared) 
) ;

// if k2==1 AND k3==1, then the focal length equation is not solvable 
// but the focal length is not needed to calculate the ratio.
// I am still trying to figure out under which circumstances k2 and k3 become 1
// but it seems to be when the rectangle is not distorted by perspective, 
// i.e. viewed straight on. Then the equation is obvious:
if (k2==1 && k3==1) whRatio = sqrt( 
    (sqr(m2y-m1y) + sqr(m2x-m1x)) / 
    (sqr(m3y-m1y) + sqr(m3x-m1x))


// After testing, I found that the above equations 
// actually give the height/width ratio of the rectangle, 
// not the width/height ratio. 
// If someone can find the error that caused this, 
// I would be most grateful.
// until then:
whRatio = 1/whRatio;
```

### Update: here is how these equations were determined:

The following is code in [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/).
It can be accessed online at http://www.sagenb.org/home/pub/704/.
(Sage is really useful in solving equations, and useable in any browser, check it out)

```
# CALCULATING THE ASPECT RATIO OF A RECTANGLE DISTORTED BY PERSPECTIVE

#
# BIBLIOGRAPHY:
# [zhang-single]: "Single-View Geometry of A Rectangle 
#  With Application to Whiteboard Image Rectification"
#  by Zhenggyou Zhang
#  http://research.microsoft.com/users/zhang/Papers/WhiteboardRectification.pdf

# pixel coordinates of the 4 corners of the quadrangle (m1, m2, m3, m4)
# see [zhang-single] figure 1
m1x = var('m1x')
m1y = var('m1y')
m2x = var('m2x')
m2y = var('m2y')
m3x = var('m3x')
m3y = var('m3y')
m4x = var('m4x')
m4y = var('m4y')

# pixel coordinates of the principal point of the image
# for a normal camera this will be the center of the image, 
# i.e. u0=IMAGEWIDTH/2; v0 =IMAGEHEIGHT/2
# This assumption does not hold if the image has been cropped asymmetrically
u0 = var('u0')
v0 = var('v0')

# pixel aspect ratio; for a normal camera pixels are square, so s=1
s = var('s')

# homogenous coordinates of the quadrangle
m1 = vector ([m1x,m1y,1])
m2 = vector ([m2x,m2y,1])
m3 = vector ([m3x,m3y,1])
m4 = vector ([m4x,m4y,1])


# the following equations are later used in calculating the the focal length 
# and the rectangle's aspect ratio.
# temporary variables: k2, k3, n2, n3

# see [zhang-single] Equation 11, 12
k2_ = m1.cross_product(m4).dot_product(m3) / m2.cross_product(m4).dot_product(m3)
k3_ = m1.cross_product(m4).dot_product(m2) / m3.cross_product(m4).dot_product(m2)
k2 = var('k2')
k3 = var('k3')

# see [zhang-single] Equation 14,16
n2 = k2 * m2 - m1
n3 = k3 * m3 - m1


# the focal length of the camera.
f = var('f')
# see [zhang-single] Equation 21
f_ = sqrt(
         -1 / (
          n2[2]*n3[2]*s^2
         ) * (
          (
           n2[0]*n3[0] - (n2[0]*n3[2]+n2[2]*n3[0])*u0 + n2[2]*n3[2]*u0^2
          )*s^2 + (
           n2[1]*n3[1] - (n2[1]*n3[2]+n2[2]*n3[1])*v0 + n2[2]*n3[2]*v0^2
          ) 
         ) 
        )


# standard pinhole camera matrix
# see [zhang-single] Equation 1
A = matrix([[f,0,u0],[0,s*f,v0],[0,0,1]])


#the width/height ratio of the original rectangle
# see [zhang-single] Equation 20
whRatio = sqrt (
               (n2*A.transpose()^(-1) * A^(-1)*n2.transpose()) / 
               (n3*A.transpose()^(-1) * A^(-1)*n3.transpose())
              )
```

The simplified equations in the c-code where determined by

```
print "simplified equations, assuming u0=0, v0=0, s=1"
print "k2 := ", k2_
print "k3 := ", k3_
print "f  := ", f_(u0=0,v0=0,s=1)
print "whRatio := ", whRatio(u0=0,v0=0,s=1)

    simplified equations, assuming u0=0, v0=0, s=1
    k2 :=  ((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)/((m2y
    - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x)
    k3 :=  ((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)/((m3y
    - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x)
    f  :=  sqrt(-((k3*m3y - m1y)*(k2*m2y - m1y) + (k3*m3x - m1x)*(k2*m2x
    - m1x))/((k3 - 1)*(k2 - 1)))
    whRatio :=  sqrt(((k2 - 1)^2 + (k2*m2y - m1y)^2/f^2 + (k2*m2x -
    m1x)^2/f^2)/((k3 - 1)^2 + (k3*m3y - m1y)^2/f^2 + (k3*m3x -
    m1x)^2/f^2))

print "Everything in one equation:"
print "whRatio := ", whRatio(f=f_)(k2=k2_,k3=k3_)(u0=0,v0=0,s=1)

    Everything in one equation:
    whRatio :=  sqrt(((((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) -
    1)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)/((m2y -
    m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - 1)*(((m1y -
    m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m2y/((m2y - m4y)*m3x
    - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - m1y)^2/((((m1y - m4y)*m2x -
    (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3y/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x -
    m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) - m1y)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x -
    m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m2y/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y
    + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - m1y) + (((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y +
    m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3x/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y
    - m3y*m4x) - m1x)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)*m2x/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x)
    - m1x)) + (((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) -
    1)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)/((m2y -
    m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - 1)*(((m1y -
    m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m2x/((m2y - m4y)*m3x
    - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - m1x)^2/((((m1y - m4y)*m2x -
    (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3y/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x -
    m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) - m1y)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x -
    m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m2y/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y
    + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - m1y) + (((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y +
    m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3x/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y
    - m3y*m4x) - m1x)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)*m2x/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x)
    - m1x)) - (((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) -
    1)^2)/((((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) -
    1)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)/((m2y -
    m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - 1)*(((m1y -
    m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3y/((m3y - m4y)*m2x
    - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) - m1y)^2/((((m1y - m4y)*m2x -
    (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3y/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x -
    m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) - m1y)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x -
    m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m2y/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y
    + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - m1y) + (((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y +
    m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3x/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y
    - m3y*m4x) - m1x)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)*m2x/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x)
    - m1x)) + (((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) -
    1)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)/((m2y -
    m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - 1)*(((m1y -
    m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3x/((m3y - m4y)*m2x
    - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) - m1x)^2/((((m1y - m4y)*m2x -
    (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3y/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x -
    m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) - m1y)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x -
    m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m2y/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y
    + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x) - m1y) + (((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y +
    m1x*m4y - m1y*m4x)*m3x/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y
    - m3y*m4x) - m1x)*(((m1y - m4y)*m3x - (m1x - m4x)*m3y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)*m2x/((m2y - m4y)*m3x - (m2x - m4x)*m3y + m2x*m4y - m2y*m4x)
    - m1x)) - (((m1y - m4y)*m2x - (m1x - m4x)*m2y + m1x*m4y -
    m1y*m4x)/((m3y - m4y)*m2x - (m3x - m4x)*m2y + m3x*m4y - m3y*m4x) -
    1)^2))
```

```
# some testing:
# - choose a random rectangle, 
# - project it onto a random plane,
# - insert the corners in the above equations,
# - check if the aspect ratio is correct.

from sage.plot.plot3d.transform import rotate_arbitrary

#redundandly random rotation matrix
rand_rotMatrix = \
           rotate_arbitrary((uniform(-5,5),uniform(-5,5),uniform(-5,5)),uniform(-5,5)) *\
           rotate_arbitrary((uniform(-5,5),uniform(-5,5),uniform(-5,5)),uniform(-5,5)) *\
           rotate_arbitrary((uniform(-5,5),uniform(-5,5),uniform(-5,5)),uniform(-5,5))

#random translation vector
rand_transVector = vector((uniform(-10,10),uniform(-10,10),uniform(-10,10))).transpose()

#random rectangle parameters
rand_width =uniform(0.1,10)
rand_height=uniform(0.1,10)
rand_left  =uniform(-10,10)
rand_top   =uniform(-10,10)

#random focal length and principal point
rand_f  = uniform(0.1,100)
rand_u0 = uniform(-100,100)
rand_v0 = uniform(-100,100)

# homogenous standard pinhole projection, see [zhang-single] Equation 1
hom_projection = A * rand_rotMatrix.augment(rand_transVector)

# construct a random rectangle in the plane z=0, then project it randomly 
rand_m1hom = hom_projection*vector((rand_left           ,rand_top            ,0,1)).transpose()
rand_m2hom = hom_projection*vector((rand_left           ,rand_top+rand_height,0,1)).transpose()
rand_m3hom = hom_projection*vector((rand_left+rand_width,rand_top            ,0,1)).transpose()
rand_m4hom = hom_projection*vector((rand_left+rand_width,rand_top+rand_height,0,1)).transpose()

#change type from 1x3 matrix to vector
rand_m1hom = rand_m1hom.column(0)
rand_m2hom = rand_m2hom.column(0)
rand_m3hom = rand_m3hom.column(0)
rand_m4hom = rand_m4hom.column(0)

#normalize
rand_m1hom = rand_m1hom/rand_m1hom[2]
rand_m2hom = rand_m2hom/rand_m2hom[2]
rand_m3hom = rand_m3hom/rand_m3hom[2]
rand_m4hom = rand_m4hom/rand_m4hom[2]

#substitute random values for f, u0, v0
rand_m1hom = rand_m1hom(f=rand_f,s=1,u0=rand_u0,v0=rand_v0)
rand_m2hom = rand_m2hom(f=rand_f,s=1,u0=rand_u0,v0=rand_v0)
rand_m3hom = rand_m3hom(f=rand_f,s=1,u0=rand_u0,v0=rand_v0)
rand_m4hom = rand_m4hom(f=rand_f,s=1,u0=rand_u0,v0=rand_v0)

# printing the randomly choosen values
print "ground truth: f=", rand_f, "; ratio=", rand_width/rand_height

# substitute all the variables in the equations:
print "calculated: f= ",\
f_(k2=k2_,k3=k3_)(s=1,u0=rand_u0,v0=rand_v0)(
  m1x=rand_m1hom[0],m1y=rand_m1hom[1],
  m2x=rand_m2hom[0],m2y=rand_m2hom[1],
  m3x=rand_m3hom[0],m3y=rand_m3hom[1],
  m4x=rand_m4hom[0],m4y=rand_m4hom[1],
),"; 1/ratio=", \
1/whRatio(f=f_)(k2=k2_,k3=k3_)(s=1,u0=rand_u0,v0=rand_v0)(
  m1x=rand_m1hom[0],m1y=rand_m1hom[1],
  m2x=rand_m2hom[0],m2y=rand_m2hom[1],
  m3x=rand_m3hom[0],m3y=rand_m3hom[1],
  m4x=rand_m4hom[0],m4y=rand_m4hom[1],
)

print "k2 = ", k2_(
  m1x=rand_m1hom[0],m1y=rand_m1hom[1],
  m2x=rand_m2hom[0],m2y=rand_m2hom[1],
  m3x=rand_m3hom[0],m3y=rand_m3hom[1],
  m4x=rand_m4hom[0],m4y=rand_m4hom[1],
), "; k3 = ", k3_(
  m1x=rand_m1hom[0],m1y=rand_m1hom[1],
  m2x=rand_m2hom[0],m2y=rand_m2hom[1],
  m3x=rand_m3hom[0],m3y=rand_m3hom[1],
  m4x=rand_m4hom[0],m4y=rand_m4hom[1],
)

# ATTENTION: testing revealed, that the whRatio 
# is actually the height/width ratio, 
# not the width/height ratio
# This contradicts [zhang-single]
# if anyone can find the error that caused this, I'd be grateful

    ground truth: f= 72.1045134124554 ; ratio= 3.46538779959142
    calculated: f=  72.1045134125 ; 1/ratio= 3.46538779959
    k2 =  0.99114614987 ; k3 =  1.57376280159
```

Comment: Thank you, Hugo. You should not use == operator when working with doubles. Better if you write code like this:
<code>
double kk = (k3 - 1)*(k2 - 1);
if (abs(kk) < 0.0001) {
  // there is no perspective distortion... use formula 2
} else {
  // there is perspective distortion... use formula 1
}
</code>

Comment: Regarding the height/width / width/height problem: I don't see how you would know that. Given only an image the objects ratio could be both, couldn't it? What is widht and what is height is usually just a convention.

Comment: And for others trying to implement this: take care about the order of the vertices, they are *not* counter-clockwise, but some sort of zig-zag. Take a look in the paper.

Comment: Can anybody state what kind of error rate is to be expected? I'm getting 0-30% which is quite big...

Comment: With regards to the k2==1 or k3==1 problem, according to the paper it occurs when the image transformation is a rectangle, so you'd have the aspect ratio. In my experience it suffices if two of the line segments of the projected quadrilateral are parallel - the other two need not be, as the paper concludes. For instance if (m1 - m2) and (m4 - m3) are parallel, k2 will always be 1, leading to singularity. I've yet to figure out where the error lies with either my reasoning or the reasoning in the paper.

Comment: +1 A word of caution to the readers. I have implemented the solution proposed here, while checking that the equations match with those in the actual paper. I am getting **runaway** numerical instability as soon I get close to the situation where any two input segments are parallel. This seems to be only partially addressed by this solution (the `(k2==1 && k3==1)` check is not enough, not even applying tolerances). I am investigating and will provide more detail if I can, but in the meantime I urge you to be especially wary of this piece of code.

Comment: Could the difference in width/heigh height/width ratio be due to a difference in coordinate system interpretation? That one assumes UV coordinates (first axis horizontal), and the other assumes matrix access similar to numpy (first axis defines rows)?

Comment: @1resu regarding accuracy I get pretty good results on synthetic images, but on actual photographs I get rather varying results. This leads me to believe that lens distortion plays an important role.

Comment: I am actually looking for positioning the camera in 3d world to minimize the perspective effect up-to some tolerance. Is there any paper or technique that you may want to share. Any hints will be greatly appreciated [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75744/perspective-correction-by-re-positioning-camera)

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

After reading your update, and looking at the first reference (Whiteboard scanning and image enhancement), I see where the missing point is.

The input data of the problem is a quadruple (A,B,C,D), **AND** the center O of the projected image.  In the article, it corresponds to the assumption u0=v0=0.  Adding this point, the problem becomes constrained enough to get the aspect ratio of the rectangle.

The problem is then restated as follows: Given a quadruple (A,B,C,D) in the Z=0 plane, find the eye position E(0,0,h), h>0 and a 3D plane P such that the projection of (A,B,C,D) on P is a rectangle.

Note that P is determined by E: to get a parallelogram, P must contain parallels to (EU) and (EV), where U=(AB)x(CD) and V=(AD)x(BC).

Experimentally, it seems that this problem has in general one unique solution, corresponding to a unique value of the w/h ratio of the rectangle.

[image]
[image]

**Previous Post**

No, you can't determine the rectangle ratio from the projection.

In the general case, a quadruple (A,B,C,D) of four non collinear points of the Z=0 plane is the projection of infinitely many rectangles, with infinitely many width/height ratios.

Consider the two vanishing points U, intersection of (AB) and (CD) and V, intersection of (AD) and (BC), and the point I, intersection of the two diagonals (AC) and (BD).  To project as ABCD, a parallelogram of center I must lie on a plane containing the line parallel to (UV) through point I.  On one such plane, you can find many rectangles projecting to ABCD, all with a different w/h ratio.

See these two images done with Cabri 3D. In the two cases ABCD is unchanged (on the gray Z=0 plane), and the blue plane containing the rectangle is not changed either. The green line partially hidden is the (UV) line and the visible green line is parallel to it and contains I.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Excuse me, but this doesn't look right. You appear to have moved the camera between these two cases, which will change the appearance of ABCD. Projecting onto a plane like this is only approximately correct at best, and you've broken the rules.

Comment: Yes, the eye is at the intersection of the red lines.  You're right that the position of the camera changes between the two views.  What does not change is the input of the problem: the projected ABCD.

Comment: Excuse me, but you're wrong. You're projecting onto the wrong plane. If I construct a 2:1 rectangle, give it position and orientation, and place the camera, do you think you can find a 3:1 rectangle that looks the same to the camera?

Comment: In the question as I understood it, we only have the projected rectangle as input (ABCD on the gray plane). We don't know anything about the projection, so we can assume it is defined by a point and a plane.

Then the question can be restated as: do all the rectangles of the 3D space projecting into ABCD have the same w/h ratio?

Comment: Without moving the camera, I don't think we can project a 2:1 and a 3:1 rectangle to the same ABCD in the general case. But as I said in a previous comment, this is not the original problem, where we don't know where the camera is.

Answer (score 1):

Size isnt really needed, and neither are proportions.  And knowing which side is up is kind of irrelevant considering he's using photos/scans of documents.  I doubt hes going to scan the back sides of them.

"Corner intersection" is the method to correct perspective.  This might be of help:

[How to draw a Perspective-Correct Grid in 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530396/how-to-draw-a-perspective-correct-grid-in-2d)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if I understand this fully: 
Using the information given in the linked answer, I can map the quadrangle in the picture to an arbitrary rectangle, by subdividing at the intersection of the diagonals.

What I would like to do is map the quadrangle to a rectangle with the correct proportions. So a picture of a square should be mapped only to a square. 

I am not sure how to get the ratio of sides. Googling for "corner intersection" did not work.

Comment: If you continue to intersect down until the rectangles are smaller than pixels, from there you can measure the height and width... then you would know how big to create your destination rectangle.. then just map backwards from there.

Comment: I am not sure how that would work. When I intersect the original quadrangle n times, i will get 2^n * 2^n smaller quadrangles. Even if they are smaller than pixels, they still have the exact same proportions as the original quadrangle, and the original quadrangle will be exactly 2^n small_quadrangles high and 2^n small quadrangles wide. If I map each small quadrangle to a pixel, I will end up with a square.

Comment: If both height and width intersection became smaller than pixel height/width on the same iteration, then yes you would have a square.  If Height took twice as many iterations as width, you have a 2:1 H:W ratio... get it?

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but I do not get it at all. 
Using the examples shown here: 
http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_persp.htm
If I intersect the quadrangle ABCD into smaller and smaller similar sub-quadrangles, I will eventually get sub-quadrangles smaller than a pixel. But on which iteration that happens depends: close to the CD side, the sub-quadrangles will be smaller than the ones close to the AB side of the original quadrangle. So the value I get seems arbitrary, and I do not understand how this is related to the ratio of the undistorted rectangle.

Comment: What I'm saying is the subdivided quad may have it's HEIGHT smaller than a pixel, without its WIDTH being there yet.  At which point you keep going until WIDTH is also smaller than a pixel.  So you would have number of iterations that took to get height (lets say 10) and however many interations that got you to width (lets say 12) which means you have a 10:12 height to width ratio.

Answer (score 1):

On the question of why the results give h/w rather then w/h:
I'm wondering if the expression of Equation 20 above is correct.
Posted is:

```
       whRatio = sqrt (
            (n2*A.transpose()^(-1) * A^(-1)*n2.transpose()) / 
            (n3*A.transpose()^(-1) * A^(-1)*n3.transpose())
           )
```

When I try to execute that with OpenCV, I get an exception.  But everything works correctly when I use the following equation which to me looks more like Equation 20:
But based on Equation 20, it looks like it should be:

```
        whRatio = sqrt (
            (n2.transpose()*A.transpose()^(-1) * A^(-1)*n2) /
            (n3.transpose()*A.transpose()^(-1) * A^(-1)*n3)
           )
```

Comment: This is odd, those operations shouldn't even be defined. I don't know much about SAGE, but it seems n2 and n3 are transposed in comparison with the paper. At least I cannot put your sugestion to work in SAGE, as the operations are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine  width / height by this answer [Calculating rectangle 3D coordinate with coordinate its shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643692/calculating-rectangle-3d-coordinate-with-coordinate-its-shadow). Assume that your rectangle rotate on intersection diagonal point calculate it width and height. But when you change distance between  the assumption shadow plane to the real shadow plane proportional of rectangle is the same with calculated width / height!

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible to know the width of this rectangle without knowing the distance of the 'camera'.

a small rectangle viewed from 5 centimeters distance looks the same as a huge rectangle as seen from meters away

Comment: Partially correct. Not only do you need to know the distance, you need to know the field of view of the camera as well.  i.e. a typical 35mm camera has a view angle of 54 degrees with no zoom.

Comment: one would probably also need to know the rotation, since it's unclear which side is up

Comment: I do not need the width, just the proportions, i.e. the quotient (width / height). The scale is of course dependent on the distance to the observer, but as far as I can tell, the proportions are not. a 1by1 square will map to different projections than a 1by2 rectangle, correct?

Comment: as a side note you can calculate the distance if you know the original high or width of one thing in the image (Person,Car,pencil,...)

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right isosceles triangle with those two vanishing points and a third point below the horizon (that is, on the same side of the horizon as the rectangle is). That third point will be our origin and the two lines to the vanishing points will be our axes. Call the distance from the origin to a vanishing point pi/2. Now extend the sides of the rectangle from the vanishing points to the axes, and mark where they intersect the axes. Pick an axis, measure the distances from the two marks to the origin, transform those distances: x->tan(x), and the difference will be the "true" length of that side. Do the same for the other axis. Take the ratio of those two lengths and you're done.

Comment: I think I get it! Something like this: 
http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/4273/perspectivediagramisoskh.jpg

I have to think about this a bit more, but at first glance I think that is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! 

(by the way, I see that you simplified your answer a bit, but I found the original comments about the origin being the point below the camera, and assuming the camera to be at a distance of 1 very useful too)

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around this method. Is it possible to extend it for the degenerate case, when one of the vanishing points is close to infinity, i.e. when two sides of the quadrangle are parallel or almost parallel?

Comment: Yes, that image captures it. This method is actually just approximate, and doesn't work well in some extreme cases. In the exact solution, the lines to the vanishing point aren't lines, they're curves (that's right, 2-point perspective is bunk), and the math is a little harder; I'll post some graphics if I can figure out how. If the figure is almost a rectangle, it's face-on and you can just do x->tan(x). If it's almost a parallelogram with non-right-angles, it's very small and you're sunk.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has an extensive article on their tech blog where they describe how they solved the problem for their scanner app.

https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2016/08/fast-document-rectification-and-enhancement/

> Rectifying a Document
>
> We assume that the input document is rectangular in the physical world, but if it is not exactly facing the camera, the resulting corners in the image will be a general convex quadrilateral. So to satisfy our first goal, we must undo the geometric transform applied by the capture process. This transformation depends on the viewpoint of the camera relative to the document (these are the so-called extrinsic parameters), in addition to things like the focal length of the camera (the intrinsic parameters). Here’s a diagram of the capture scenario:
>
> In order to undo the geometric transform, we must first determine the said parameters. If we assume a nicely symmetric camera (no astigmatism, no skew, et cetera), the unknowns in this model are:
>
> - the 3D location of the camera relative to the document (3 degrees of freedom),
> - the 3D orientation of the camera relative to the document (3 degrees of freedom),
> - the dimensions of the document (2 degrees of freedom), and
> - the focal length of the camera (1 degree of freedom).
>
> On the flip side, the x- and y-coordinates of the four detected document corners gives us effectively eight constraints. While there are seemingly more unknowns (9) than constraints (8), the unknowns are not entirely free variables—one could imagine scaling the document physically and placing it further from the camera, to obtain an identical photo. This relation places an additional constraint, so we have a fully constrained system to be solved. (The actual system of equations we solve involves a few other considerations; the relevant Wikipedia article gives a good summary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning)
>
> Once the parameters have been recovered, we can undo the geometric transform applied by the capture process to obtain a nice rectangular image. However, this is potentially a time-consuming process: one would look up, for each output pixel, the value of the corresponding input pixel in the source image. Of course, GPUs are specifically designed for tasks like this: rendering a texture in a virtual space. There exists a view transform—which happens to be the inverse of the camera transform we just solved for!—with which one can render the full input image and obtain the rectified document. (An easy way to see this is to note that once you have the full input image on the screen of your phone, you can tilt and translate the phone such that the projection of the document region on the screen appears rectilinear to you.)
>
> Lastly, recall that there was an ambiguity with respect to scale: we can’t tell whether the document was a letter-sized paper (8.5” x 11”) or a poster board (17” x 22”), for instance. What should the dimensions of the output image be? To resolve this ambiguity, we count the number of pixels within the quadrilateral in the input image, and set the output resolution as to match this pixel count. The idea is that we don’t want to upsample or downsample the image too much.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to still be some confusion on this interesting problem. I want to give an easy-to-follow explanation for when the problem can and cannot be solved.

**Constraints and Degrees of Freedom**

Typically when we are faced with a problem like this the first thing to do is to assess the number of unknown Degrees of Freedom (DoFs)  N, and the number of independent equations M that we have for constraining the unknown  DoFs. It is impossible to solve the problem if N if exceeds M (meaning there are fewer constraints than unknowns). We can rule out all problems where this is the case as being unsolvable. If N does not exceed M then it *may* be possible to solve the problem with a unique solution, but this is not guaranteed (see the second to last paragraph for an example).

Let's use **p**1, **p**2, **p**3 and **p**4 to denote the positions of the 4 corners of the planar surface in world coordinates. Let's use **R** and **t** to be the 3D rotation and translation that transforms these to camera coordinates. Let's use **K** to denote the 3x3  camera intrinsic matrix. We will ignore lens distortion for now. The 2D position of the *i*th corner in the camera's image is given by **q**i=f(**K**(**Rp**i+**t**)) where f is the projection function f(x,y,z)=(x/z,y/z). Using this equation we know that each corner in the image gives us two equations (i.e. two constraints) on our unknowns: one from the x component of **q**i and one from the y component. So we have a total of 8 constraints to work with. The official name of these constraints are the *reprojection constraints*.

So what are our unknown DoFs? Certainly **R** and **t** are unknown, because we do not know the camera's pose in world coordinates. Therefore we have already 6 unknown DoFs: 3 for **R** (e.g. yaw, pitch and roll) and 3 for **t**.  Therefore there can be a maximal of *two* unknowns in the remaining terms (**K**, **p**1, **p**2, **p**3, **p**4).

**Different problems**

We can construct different problems depending on which two terms in (**K**, **p**1, **p**2, **p**3, **p**4) we shall consider as unknown. At this point let's write out **K** in the usual form: **K**=(fx, 0, cx; 0, fy, cy; 0,0,1) where fx and fy are the focal length terms (fx/fy is normally called the image aspect ratio) and (cx,cy) is the principal point (the centre of projection in the image).

We could obtain one problem by having fx and fy as our two unknowns, and assume (cx, cy, **p**1, **p**2, **p**3, **p**4) are all known. Indeed this very problem is used and solved within OpenCV's camera calibration method, using images of a checkerboard planar target. This is used to get an initial estimate for fx and fy, by assuming that the principal point is at the image centre (which is a very reasonable assumption for most cameras).

Alternatively we can create a different problem by assuming fx=fy, which again is quite reasonable for many cameras, and assume this focal length (denoted as f) is the *only* unknown in **K**. Therefore we still have one unknowns left to play with (recall we can have a maximum of two unknowns). So let's use this by supposing we known the shape of the plane: as a rectangle (which was the original assumption in the question). Therefore we can define the corners as follows: **p**1=(0,0,0), **p**2=(0,w,0), **p**3=(h,0,0) and **p**4=(h,w,0), where h and w denotes the height and width of the rectangle. Now, because we only have 1 unknown left, let us set this as the plane's aspect ratio: x=w/h. Now the question is can we simultaneously recover x, f, **R** and **t** from the 8 reprojection constraints? The answer it turns out is yes! And the solution is given in Zhang's paper cited in the question.

**The scale ambiguity**

One might wonder if another problem can be solved: if we assume **K** is known and the 2 unknowns are h and w.  Can they be solved from the reprojection equations? The answer is no, and is because there is an ambiguity between the size of the plane and the plane's depth to the camera. Specifically if we scale the corners **p**i by s and scale **t** by s, then s cancels in the reprojection equations. Therefore the absolute scale of the plane is not recoverable.

There may be other problems with different combinations for the unknown DoFs, for example having **R**, **t**, one of the principal point components and the plane"s width as unknowns. However one needs to think of which cases are of practical use. Nevertheless I haven't yet seen a systematic set of solutions for all useful combinations!

**More points**

We might think that if we were to add extra point correspondences between the plane and the image, or exploit the edges of the plane, we could recover more than 8 unknown DoFs. Sadly the answer is no. This is because they don't add any extra independent constraints. The reason is because the 4 corners describe *completely* the transform from the plane to the image. This can be seen by fitting a homography matrix using the four corners, which can then determine the positions of all other points on the plane in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python implementation of https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/2016/11/Digital-Signal-Processing.pdf

```
import numpy as np


def find_rectangle_proportion(K, m1, m2, m3, m4):
    # Detailed computations
    # https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/2016/11/Digital-Signal-Processing.pdf

    # m1 = top_left, m2 = top_right, m3 = bottom_left, m4 = bottom_right

    # Make homeneous coordinates
    m1 = np.array([m1[0], m1[1], 1])
    m2 = np.array([m2[0], m2[1], 1])
    m3 = np.array([m3[0], m3[1], 1])
    m4 = np.array([m4[0], m4[1], 1])

    # (11)
    k2 = np.dot(np.cross(m1, m4), m3) / np.dot(np.cross(m2, m4), m3)
    # (12)
    k3 = np.dot(np.cross(m1, m4), m2) / np.dot(np.cross(m3, m4), m2)

    # (14)
    n2 = k2 * m2 - m1
    # (16)
    n3 = k3 * m3 - m1

    inv_K = np.linalg.inv(K)
    KK = np.dot(inv_K.T, inv_K)

    # ratio width/height (20)
    ratio = np.sqrt(np.dot(n2, np.dot(KK, n2)) / np.dot(n3, np.dot(KK, n3)))

    return ratio


if __name__ == "__main__":
    top_left = [269, 25]
    top_right = [800, 19]
    bottom_right = [805, 748]
    bottom_left = [273, 750]

    # Load intrinsic matrices from calib.py
    K = np.load("calibration_pixel_6a/intrinsic.npy")

    ratio = find_rectangle_proportion(K, top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right)
    print(f"ratio width/height = {ratio}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need more information, that transformed figure could come from any parallelogram given an arbitrary perspective.

So I guess you need to do some kind of calibration first.

**Edit:** for those who said that I was wrong, here goes the mathematical proof that there are infinite combinations of rectangles/cameras that yield to the same projection:

In order to simplify the problem (as we only need the ratio of the sides) let's assume that our rectangle is defined by the following points: `R=[(0,0),(1,0),(1,r),(0,r)]` (this simplification is the same as transforming any problem to an equivalent one in an affine space).

The transformed polygon is defined as: `T=[(tx0,ty0),(tx1,ty1),(tx2,ty2),(tx3,ty3)]`

There exists a transformation matrix `M = [[m00,m01,m02],[m10,m11,m12],[m20,m21,m22]]` that satisfies `(Rxi,Ryi,1)*M=wi(txi,tyi,1)'`

if we expand the equation above for the points,

for `R_0` we get: `m02-tx0*w0 = m12-ty0*w0 = m22-w0 = 0`

for `R_1` we get: `m00-tx1*w1 = m10-ty1*w1 = m20+m22-w1 = 0`

for `R_2` we get: `m00+r*m01-tx2*w2 = m10+r*m11-ty2*w2 = m20+r*m21+m22-w2 = 0`

and for `R_3` we get: `m00+r*m01-tx3*w3 = m10+r*m11-ty3*w3 = m20 + r*m21 + m22 -w3 = 0`

So far we have 12 equations, 14 unknown variables (9 from the matrix, 4 from the `wi`, and 1 for the ratio `r`) and the rest are known values (`txi` and `tyi` are given).

Even if the system weren't underspecified, some of the unknowns are multiplied among themselves (`r` and `mi0` products) making the system non linear (you could transform it to a linear system assigning a new name to each product, but you'll end still with 13 unknowns, and 3 of them being expanded to infinite solutions).

If you can find any flaw in the reasoning or the maths, please let me know.

Comment: But he knows its a rectangle.  i.e. scanned documents.

Comment: @Neil N So what? Maybe now the rectangles are not parallelograms and I haven't noticed...

Comment: because rectangles have all 90 degree corners, which takes the possible rotations down from infinity to one (well technically two if you consider he could be looking at the back side).  A huge difference.

Comment: but there's still an infinite number of different rectangles that can look the same if the correct perspective is applied.

Comment: that's what I was wondering. As far as I can tell, a rectangle with (width=2*height) has a different set of possible projections than a rectangle with (width=3*height). 
So looking at a given perspective projection, there will be an infinite number of possible rectangles, but they will all have the same ratio of width to height.

Comment: I think I'll have to find a counter-example

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning. The transformation in question is NOT just a rotation, so what is the justification for your "there exists" line? (And why not just give us a counter-example?)

Comment: If it were just a rotation I would have used a 2x2 matrix and cartesian coordinates, not a 3x3 and homogeneous coordinates. It's expected to know a little bit about perspective projections to follow the reasoning, hence the "there exists" line. A demonstration is better than a counter example, but if you want one, you can fill the values that are supposed given in the equations, solve them (doing the trick to assign new variables to the non-linear products to make them linear) and then you'll have all the counterexamples you can ever wish for.

Comment: I admit I had never heard of homogenous coordinates before, but now that I've read up a little on them it still seems that you are assuming what you're trying to prove. I will eat my words if you give a counter-example-- shall I construct the 2:1 rectangle and place the camera?

Comment: fortran i think you mix things up based on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/442002/85945) the can be calculated the only unknown think will be the camera distance like @Toad already suggested which is the part we need to get the original size