# How to detect rectangle from HoughLines transform in OpenCV Java

Tags: java, opencv

I know this is duplicated post but still get stuck on implementation.
I following some guide on the internet in how to detect document in an image in OpenCV and Java.
The first approarch i came up with is that use the findContours after pre-process some image processing like blur, edge detection, after get all the contours i can found the largest contour and assume that is a rectangle i'm looking for but it fail in some case, e.g the document is not fully taken like missing one corner.
After trying several time and some new processing but does not work at all, i found that the HoughLine transform take it easier. From now i have all the line inside an image but still do not what to do next to defined the interest rectangle that i want.
Here is the implementation code i have so far:
**Approach 1: Using findContours**

```
Mat grayImage = new Mat();
    Mat detectedEdges = new Mat();
    // convert to grayscale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // reduce noise with a 3x3 kernel
    // Imgproc.blur(grayImage, detectedEdges, new Size(3, 3));
    Imgproc.medianBlur(grayImage, detectedEdges, 9);
    // Imgproc.equalizeHist(detectedEdges, detectedEdges);
    // Imgproc.GaussianBlur(detectedEdges, detectedEdges, new Size(5, 5), 0, 0, Core.BORDER_DEFAULT);
    Mat edges = new Mat();
    // canny detector, with ratio of lower:upper threshold of 3:1
    Imgproc.Canny(detectedEdges, edges, this.threshold.getValue(), this.threshold.getValue() * 3, 3, true);
    // makes the object in white bigger
    Imgproc.dilate(edges, edges, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 1); // 1
    Image imageToShow = Utils.mat2Image(edges);
    updateImageView(cannyFrame, imageToShow);
    /// Find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours(edges, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    // loop over the contours
    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve;
    double maxArea = 0;
    int maxId = -1;
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        MatOfPoint2f temp = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
        double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
        approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(temp, approxCurve, Imgproc.arcLength(temp, true) * 0.02, true);
        if (approxCurve.total() == 4 && area >= maxArea) {
            double maxCosine = 0;
            List<Point> curves = approxCurve.toList();
            for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
                double cosine = Math.abs(angle(curves.get(j % 4), curves.get(j - 2), curves.get(j - 1)));
                maxCosine = Math.max(maxCosine, cosine);
            }
            if (maxCosine < 0.3) {
                maxArea = area;
                maxId = contours.indexOf(contour);
            }
        }
    }
    MatOfPoint maxMatOfPoint = contours.get(maxId);
    MatOfPoint2f maxMatOfPoint2f = new MatOfPoint2f(maxMatOfPoint.toArray());
    RotatedRect rect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(maxMatOfPoint2f);
    System.out.println("Rect angle: " + rect.angle);
    Point points[] = new Point[4];
    rect.points(points);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        Imgproc.line(frame, points[i], points[(i + 1) % 4], new Scalar(255, 255, 25), 3);
    }

    Mat dest = new Mat();
    frame.copyTo(dest, frame);
    return dest;
```

**Apparch 2: Using HoughLine transform**

```
// STEP 1: Edge detection
    Mat grayImage = new Mat();
    Mat detectedEdges = new Mat();
    Vector<Point> start = new Vector<Point>();
    Vector<Point> end = new Vector<Point>();
    // convert to grayscale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // reduce noise with a 3x3 kernel
    // Imgproc.blur(grayImage, detectedEdges, new Size(3, 3));
    Imgproc.medianBlur(grayImage, detectedEdges, 9);
    // Imgproc.equalizeHist(detectedEdges, detectedEdges);
    // Imgproc.GaussianBlur(detectedEdges, detectedEdges, new Size(5, 5), 0, 0, Core.BORDER_DEFAULT);
    // AdaptiveThreshold -> classify as either black or white
    // Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(detectedEdges, detectedEdges, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 2);
    // Imgproc.Sobel(detectedEdges, detectedEdges, -1, 1, 0);
    Mat edges = new Mat();
    // canny detector, with ratio of lower:upper threshold of 3:1
    Imgproc.Canny(detectedEdges, edges, this.threshold.getValue(), this.threshold.getValue() * 3, 3, true);
    // apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(edges, edges, new org.opencv.core.Size(5, 5), 5);
    // makes the object in white bigger
    Imgproc.dilate(edges, edges, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 1); // 1
    Image imageToShow = Utils.mat2Image(edges);
    updateImageView(cannyFrame, imageToShow);
    // STEP 2: Line detection
    // Do Hough line
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int minLineSize = 50;
    int lineGap = 10;
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, Math.PI / 720, (int) this.threshold.getValue(), this.minLineSize.getValue(), lineGap);
    System.out.println("MinLineSize: " + this.minLineSize.getValue());
    System.out.println(lines.rows());
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.rows(); i++) {
        double[] val = lines.get(i, 0);
        Point tmpStartP = new Point(val[0], val[1]);
        Point tmpEndP = new Point(val[2], val[3]);
        start.add(tmpStartP);
        end.add(tmpEndP);
        Imgproc.line(frame, tmpStartP, tmpEndP, new Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2);
    }

    Mat dest = new Mat();
    frame.copyTo(dest, frame);
    return dest;
```

[HoughLine result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANXrh.png) 
[HoughLine result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ap7.png)

How to detect needed rectangle from HoughLine result?
Can someone give me the next step to complete the HoughLine transform approach.
Any help is appriciated. i'm stuck with this for a while.

Thanks you for reading this.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27119734/5799975).

Comment: Thank you. i'll will try that answer.

Comment: i'm working to find intersection between lines

Comment: Can you provide the input images, so I can give it a shot?

Comment: Hi Laine, Please do, the input are stored here [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bw0Dgzp3c0xQNmZEYTdBWmdZZlU?usp=sharing]. thanks you

Comment: Hi Laine, I had the List<Point> of all corners by compute intersection between the lines. the hard job now is how to filter out the needed Point (we need 4 Points to make a rectangle). i'm stuck here. i've tried to compare with massCenter of those Point but with some image it cannot get the center, it seam to be out of an image. Do you have any idea to filter them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This answer is pretty much a mix of two other answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131530/5799975) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44090417/5799975)) I posted. But the pipeline I used for the other answers can be a little bit improved for your case. So I think it's worth posting a new answer.*

There are many ways to achieve what you want. However, I don't think that line detection with `HoughLinesP` is needed here. So here is the pipeline I used on your samples:

### Step 1: Detect egdes

- **Resize** the input image if it's too large (I noticed that this pipeline works better on down scaled version of a given input image)
- **Blur** grayscale input and detect edges with **Canny filter**

### Step 2: Find the card's corners

- Compute the **contours**
- **Sort** the contours by **length** and only keep the **largest** one
- Generate the **convex hull** of this contour
- Use `approxPolyDP` to **simplify** the convex hull (this should give a *quadrilateral*)
- Create a **mask** out of the approximate polygon
- return the 4 points of the quadrilateral

### Step 3: Homography

- Use `findHomography` to find the affine transformation of your paper sheet (with the 4 corner points found at *Step 2*)
- **Warp** the input image using the computed homography matrix

**NOTE**: Of course, once you have found the corners of the paper sheet on the down scaled version of the input image, you can easily compute the position of the corners on the full sized input image. This, in order to have the best resolution for the warped paper sheet.

And here is the result:
[image]

```
vector<Point> getQuadrilateral(Mat & grayscale, Mat& output)
{
    Mat approxPoly_mask(grayscale.rows, grayscale.cols, CV_8UC1);
    approxPoly_mask = Scalar(0);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(grayscale, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<int> indices(contours.size());
    iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

    sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&contours](int lhs, int rhs) {
        return contours[lhs].size() > contours[rhs].size();
    });

    /// Find the convex hull object for each contour
    vector<vector<Point> >hull(1);
    convexHull(Mat(contours[indices[0]]), hull[0], false);

    vector<vector<Point>> polygon(1);
    approxPolyDP(hull[0], polygon[0], 20, true);
    drawContours(approxPoly_mask, polygon, 0, Scalar(255));
    imshow("approxPoly_mask", approxPoly_mask);

    if (polygon[0].size() >= 4) // we found the 4 corners
    {
        return(polygon[0]);
    }

    return(vector<Point>());
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Mat input = imread("papersheet1.JPG");
    resize(input, input, Size(), 0.1, 0.1);
    Mat input_grey;
    cvtColor(input, input_grey, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat threshold1;
    Mat edges;
    blur(input_grey, input_grey, Size(3, 3));
    Canny(input_grey, edges, 30, 100);


    vector<Point> card_corners = getQuadrilateral(edges, input);
    Mat warpedCard(400, 300, CV_8UC3);
    if (card_corners.size() == 4)
    {
        Mat homography = findHomography(card_corners, vector<Point>{Point(warpedCard.cols, warpedCard.rows), Point(0, warpedCard.rows), Point(0, 0), Point(warpedCard.cols, 0)});
        warpPerspective(input, warpedCard, homography, Size(warpedCard.cols, warpedCard.rows));
    }

    imshow("warped card", warpedCard);
    imshow("edges", edges);
    imshow("input", input);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

This is C++ code, but it shouldn't be to hard to translate into Java.

Comment: Hi Laine, Thanks for your patient and your time. I'll try to apply your approach and see how it work and improve if can.

Comment: Hi Laine, I apply your approach success in java and the result as same as you did. We know that there are many way to get the job done in OpenCV (findContours, HoughLineP) Do you know the Pros and Cons of those approach. i'm new in this section and try to dig about this detection area. thanks for your intesrest.

Comment: Hi Laine, After try your appoarch, i try to use HoughLineP to get the same result but even we get the clean image with the only rectangle Mat after findLargestContour, the result of Lines and Corners (compute intersection between those Lines) using HoughLineP does not seams good. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Parker, the major drawback of my approach is that if the largest contour doesn't contain the 4 corners of the paper sheet, then the following steps won't be correct and the result will be bad (one corner will be missing for instance). Using `HoughLinesP` to find the 4 sides (and thus the 4 corners) may be a step towards a more robust pipeline. However, you will have to figure out a way to find which Lines correspond to the paper sheet's sides (which are not necessarily the 4 longest Lines).

Comment: @Parker, Have you followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131530/5799975) for your second approach? It's hard to tell what's going wrong. Maybe you don't compute the intersection between the right pairs of lines.

Comment: @Laine: you are right, your approach work very welll if the image or video frame contains all 4 cornor of paper sheet but if one is missing then it wont work anymore that is why i want to try use HoughLineP to find the document event missing one corner. but still not good enough. now i'm working on OCR using tesseract, the result is not good at all, anyway thank for your time.

Comment: @Laine: Hi realize that the using the HoughLineP is robust approach to detect document and rectification but i got stuck in how to detect 4 strongest and longest line represent a document shape. some questions are: How to join or dismiss close by lines or points, or lines that have same directions. Do you have any idea to make it work? now i have List<Line> or List<Point> represent Lines as the result of HoughLineP. Please if you have any idea