# Detect card MinArea Quadrilateral from contour OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Yet another about detecting card in a picture.
I've managed to pretty much isolate the card in the picture, I have a convex hull that is close and from here I'm stuck.

For the context/constraint, objective:

- Detect a card in a picture
- Plain-ish background (see example)
- Type of card fixed ahead (meaning: we have the width/height ratio)
- One object per picture (for now at least)

Approach I used:

1. Downscale
2. Gray-scale
3. Light Blur
4. Canny
5. Find contours
6. Remove all contours in list with less than 120 points (try/error value)
7. Case 1: I have 1 contour: perfect contour of my card: step 9
8. Case 2: I have multiple contour

   - Convex hull
   - Approximate polygon ?
9. ???

Step 1, 3 and 6 are mainly to remove noise and small artifacts.

So I'm pretty much stuck at step 9.
I've tried on a sample picture:

[image: Sample]

On the debug picture:

- Green: contours
- Red: convex hull
- Purple/Pink-ish: used approxPolyDp
- Yellow: minAreaRect

(the result image is extracted from the minAreaRect)

So the contour is acceptable, I can probably do a little better by tweaking the parameters from canny or the first blur.
But for now this is acceptable, the issue now is, how can I get the the 4 points that will form the "minarea quadrilateral". 
As you can see, minAreaRect gives a rectangle which is not perfect, and the approxPolyDp is losing too much of the card.

Any clue how I can approach this?
I tried playing with the epsilon value when using approxPolyDp (I used `arcLength*0.1`), but nothing.

Another issue with this approach is that is a corner is lost during canny (see example) it'll not work (unless when using minAreaRect). But this can probably be resolved before (with a better pre-processing) or after (since we know the width/height ratio).

[image]

Not asking for code here, just ideas how to approach this,

thanks!

**Edit**: Yves Daoust's solutions:

- Get the 8 points from the convex hull that match the predicate:
  (maximize x, x+y, y, -x+y, -x, -x-y, -y, x-y)
- From this octagon, take 4 longest sides, get the intersection points

Result:

[image: result]

**Edit 2:** Using Hough transform (instead of 8 extreme points) gives me better result for all cases where the 4 sides are found. If more than 4 lines are found, probably we have duplicates, so use some maths to try to filter and keep 4 lines. I coded a draft working by using the determinant (close to 0 if parallel) and the point-line distance formula)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the pipeline I tried on your input image:

### Step 1: Detect egdes

- **Blur** grayscale input and detect edges with **Canny filter**

### Step 2: Find the card's corners

- Compute the **contours**
- **Sort** the contours by **length** and only keep the **largest** one
- Generate the **convex hull** of this contour
- Create a **mask** out of the convex hull
- Use `HoughLinesP` to find the **4 sides** of your cards
- Compute the **intersections** of the 4 sides

### Step 3: Homography

- Use `findHomography` to find the affine transformation of your card (with the 4 intersection points found at *Step 2*)
- **Warp** the input image using the computed homography matrix

And here is the result:
[image: card detection pipeline]

Note that you will have to find a way to **sort the 4 intersection points** so that there are always in the same order (otherwise `findHomography` won't work).

I know you didn't ask for code, but I had to test my pipeline so here it is... :)

```
Vec3f calcParams(Point2f p1, Point2f p2) // line's equation Params computation
{
    float a, b, c;
    if (p2.y - p1.y == 0)
    {
        a = 0.0f;
        b = -1.0f;
    }
    else if (p2.x - p1.x == 0)
    {
        a = -1.0f;
        b = 0.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        a = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
        b = -1.0f;
    }

    c = (-a * p1.x) - b * p1.y;
    return(Vec3f(a, b, c));
}

Point findIntersection(Vec3f params1, Vec3f params2)
{
    float x = -1, y = -1;
    float det = params1[0] * params2[1] - params2[0] * params1[1];
    if (det < 0.5f && det > -0.5f) // lines are approximately parallel
    {
        return(Point(-1, -1));
    }
    else
    {
        x = (params2[1] * -params1[2] - params1[1] * -params2[2]) / det;
        y = (params1[0] * -params2[2] - params2[0] * -params1[2]) / det;
    }
    return(Point(x, y));
}

vector<Point> getQuadrilateral(Mat & grayscale, Mat& output) // returns that 4 intersection points of the card
{
    Mat convexHull_mask(grayscale.rows, grayscale.cols, CV_8UC1);
    convexHull_mask = Scalar(0);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(grayscale, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<int> indices(contours.size());
    iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

    sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&contours](int lhs, int rhs) {
        return contours[lhs].size() > contours[rhs].size();
    });

    /// Find the convex hull object
    vector<vector<Point> >hull(1);
    convexHull(Mat(contours[indices[0]]), hull[0], false);

    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    drawContours(convexHull_mask, hull, 0, Scalar(255));
    imshow("convexHull_mask", convexHull_mask);
    HoughLinesP(convexHull_mask, lines, 1, CV_PI / 200, 50, 50, 10);
    cout << "lines size:" << lines.size() << endl;

    if (lines.size() == 4) // we found the 4 sides
    {
        vector<Vec3f> params(4);
        for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
        {
            params.push_back(calcParams(Point(lines[l][0], lines[l][1]), Point(lines[l][2], lines[l][3])));
        }

        vector<Point> corners;
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < params.size(); j++) // j starts at i so we don't have duplicated points
            {
                Point intersec = findIntersection(params[i], params[j]);
                if ((intersec.x > 0) && (intersec.y > 0) && (intersec.x < grayscale.cols) && (intersec.y < grayscale.rows))
                {
                    cout << "corner: " << intersec << endl;
                    corners.push_back(intersec);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++)
        {
            circle(output, corners[i], 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        }

        if (corners.size() == 4) // we have the 4 final corners
        {
            return(corners);
        }
    }
    
    return(vector<Point>());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat input = imread("playingcard_input.png");
    Mat input_grey;
    cvtColor(input, input_grey, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat threshold1;
    Mat edges;
    blur(input_grey, input_grey, Size(3, 3));
    Canny(input_grey, edges, 30, 100);

    vector<Point> card_corners = getQuadrilateral(edges, input);
    Mat warpedCard(400, 300, CV_8UC3);
    if (card_corners.size() == 4)
    {
        Mat homography = findHomography(card_corners, vector<Point>{Point(warpedCard.cols, 0), Point(warpedCard.cols, warpedCard.rows), Point(0,0) , Point(0, warpedCard.rows)});
        warpPerspective(input, warpedCard, homography, Size(warpedCard.cols, warpedCard.rows));
    }

    imshow("warped card", warpedCard);
    imshow("edges", edges);
    imshow("input", input);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I've have tweaked a little the parameters of `Canny` and `HoughLinesP` functions to have a better detection of the card (program now works on both input samples).

Comment: Ok, so similar approach, but you used approxPolyDp where I used @Yves Daoust solution. I'm curious about the fact that your approxPolyDp seems much cleaner than the one I tested. I'll investigate by checking your code, thanks!
Huge plus for the affine transformation part coming after, thanks for that too!

Comment: @badoualy Actually, I didn't use the result of `approxPolyDP` in my code. The second picture is actually the **convex hull** of the largest contour. I'll will update my answer.

Comment: @badoualy I've have tweaked a little the parameters of Canny and HoughLinesP functions to have a better detection of the card (program now works on both input samples).

Comment: Your approach relies on the fact that the largest contour will be almost a complete hull of the card, I'll still test and see what happens, maybe combine the largest contours as one cloud and see what results I get with Hough

Comment: I tried with Hough, I get better result using it (when 4 sides are found). I now have to improve it for cases when I get 5 or 6 lines with 2 lines being on the same side. Thanks!

Comment: "Your approach relies on the fact that the largest contour will be almost a complete hull of the card" That is right. " [...] improve it for cases when I get 5 or 6 lines with 2 lines being on the same side" Actually I did have a similar problem (two lines found on the same side) when I tried my code on your second sample. Maybe reducing `HoughLinesP`'s theta parameter would help?

Comment: If I do that, I'll miss 1 or 2 lines in other samples. I just did a small algo to remove duplicate (using line-point distance and determinant to identify "duplicates").

Comment: Just another thought: Dilating the **mask** created a _Step 2_ with a small kernel (1,1) would maybe help to merge lines, thus increasing the chance to find a suitable largest contour.

Answer (score 3):

As the object is isolated on a uniform background, I would recommend to start finding edges from the image outline, towards the center, and stop at the first edge points met.

Unless you get false positives in the background area, the convex hull will give you a fairly good approximation of the object outline, despite edge point misses.

Now to get the bounding quadrilateral, you can find the farthest points in the eight cardinal directions (maximize x, x+y, y, x-y, -x, -x-y, -y, -x+y). This gives you an octagon (possibly with merged vertices). Take the four longest sides and intersect them to find the corners.

[image]

Comment: Trying that, any simple way to differentiate the sides (and from the diagonal which is bigger than quadrilateral sides) ? I seem to be overthinking this

Comment: @badoualy: differentiate the sides ? The diagonals do not appear in the octagon.

Comment: Oh, I was working as a point cloud. But I do need to "order" the points in order to have them in a list (clockwise or counter clockwise) right?

Comment: If you look for the points in the indicated order, they will form a convex polygon.

Comment: Kept the same order, doesn't seem to be the case, I get a Z shaped figure.
Edit: -x-y switched with x - y and it works.

Comment: @badoualy: probably a typo in my ordering. You should be able to fix.

Comment: Ok, done, edited the post with the result, thanks for your help!