# How to find extreme points on lines using java and opencv

Tags: java, opencv

I am currently designing a lane detection program and need to fill in the area between multiple lines. How would I go about finding the extreme points (the highest point on the right and left + the lowest points on the right and left).
Here is the image I am currently working with ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t4bB.png)).

As a note, the image can be considered a coordinate plane, as all lines have a start and end point, and I can retrieve their coordinates.

Here is what I want (extreme points in blue): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtDap.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are the red marks code-wise ? contours, lines (start point, end point)...? Did you find the lines with [HoughLinesP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp)?

Comment: The red marks on the image are lines created by HoughLinesP @ElouarnLaine

Comment: Did you try my approach? Did it work for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the info and sample images provided, here is how I would approach this problem:

## Prerequisite

As the red marks are lines created by the [`HoughLinesP`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb), you have the following information on each line: **(*x1*, *y1*, *x2*, *y2*)** where **(*x1*, *y1*)** is the start point and **(*x2*, *y2*)** the end point of the line.

For testing purpose, I created 3 lines:

[image: 3 lines for testing purpose]

## Pipeline

1. Create a list of points (`contour` in my code) containing the **start** and **end points** of each line.
2. Compute the convex hull of the list of points using [`convexHull`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656).

At this point you will get something in this taste:

[image: Green convex hull without approximation]

Note that the generated hull (in green) does contain **more than 4 points** (that is, not only the *extreme points*). So what we'll do next is to simplify the hull in order to retain only the 4 *extreme points*.

3. **Simplify** the hull with [`approxPolyDP`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c)
4. The 4 remaining points of the hull should be an **approximation** of the *extreme points*.

Here you can see the final result with the approximate hull in green and the 4 extreme points in yellow:

[image: final result, extreme points in yellow]

## Python code

Finally, as a reference, here is the Python code I used (This shouldn't be to hard to port into Java):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

input_img = np.zeros((400,400,3), np.uint8)
# 3 lines added for testing purpose
lines = []
lines.append(((350,350),(250,200))) # (start point, end point)
lines.append(((50,350),(55,330)))
lines.append(((60,250),(80,200)))

contour = [] #in Java you'd use a List of Points

for line in lines:
    # we create a contour with the start and end points of each line
    contour.append(line[0])
    contour.append(line[1])
    # we draw the lines (in your case, detected by HoughLinesP)
    cv2.line(input_img,line[0],line[1],(0,0,255),3)

contour = np.array(contour)
hull = cv2.convexHull(contour) # we compute the convex hull of our contour

epsilon = 0.05*cv2.arcLength(hull,True) # epsilon may need to be tweaked
approx_hull = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull,epsilon,True)

# we check that there are only 4 points left in the approximate hull (if there are more, then you'd need to increase epsilon
if(len(approx_hull) == 4): 
    for final_point in approx_hull :
        # we draw the 4 points contained in the approximate hull 
        cv2.circle(input_img, (final_point[0][0], final_point[0][1]),5,(0,242,255),2)

cv2.drawContours(input_img, [approx_hull], 0, (0,255,0),1)
cv2.imshow("result",input_img)
```

## Alternative

I think this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128433/5799975) from @YvesDaoust could work aswell. I didn't have time to test it so please, keep me updated if you do. :)

Comment: As far as i was able to see contures will be a List<MatOfPoint> and convexHull takes in a single one, so how does that work ?