# How to apply perspective transformation to the image using open cv?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to apply perspective transformation to the image using open cv . I have the image of card in which I have converted the background color to black and foreground object
as white color as shown in below image . Now I want to apply perspective transformation on it so that image gets properly viewed ?. My code is displaying just complete black thing .

**Image:**

[image: Binary image]

**Code:**

```
import cv2,numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
input_image2 = cv2.imread("/home/hamza/Desktop/card_in_polygon_format.jpeg")

orig_im_coor = np.float32([[90, 261], [235, 386], [417, 178], [268, 83]])
height , width = 450,350
new_image_coor =  np.float32([[0, 0], [width, 0], [0, height], [width, height]])

P = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(orig_im_coor,new_image_coor)

perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(input_image2,P,(width,height))
cv2.imshow("Perspective transformation", perspective)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Note:** Every time my code will gets an image as black and white . If it capture the corners by itself too then it will be appreciate able instead of taking out it manually.

Comment: You coordinates are out of the white region. Try: `orig_im_coor = np.float32([[640, 184], [1002, 409], [211, 625], [589, 940]])`

Comment: @Rotem , How can i take out orig_im_coor points automatically by code , so that I cannot take out it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic quadrangle fitting is not so trivial...

- There is a good example in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127342/detect-card-minarea-quadrilateral-from-contour-opencv), but it's implemented in C++.
- The method I use is more like the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138000/fit-quadrilateral-tetragon-to-a-blob) - simpler, but less accurate.

The suggested solution uses the following stages:

- Find contours, (and get the largest - needed in case there is more than one).
- Approximate the contour to polygon using [cv2.approxPolyDP](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c).
  Assume the polygon is a quadrangle.
- Sort the 4 corners in the right order.
  Note: The method I used for sorting the corner is too complicated - you may sort the corners using simple logic.

---

Here is a code sample:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np


def find_corners(im):
    """ 
    Find "card" corners in a binary image.
    Return a list of points in the following format: [[640, 184], [1002, 409], [211, 625], [589, 940]] 
    The points order is top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right.
    """

    # Better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127342/detect-card-minarea-quadrilateral-from-contour-opencv

    # Find contours in img.
    cnts = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # [-2] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).

    # Find the contour with the maximum area (required if there is more than one contour).
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138000/fit-quadrilateral-tetragon-to-a-blob
    epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    box = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)

    # Draw box for testing
    tmp_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.drawContours(tmp_im, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("tmp_im", tmp_im)

    box = np.squeeze(box).astype(np.float32)  # Remove redundant dimensions


    # Sorting the points order is top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.
    # Note: 
    # The method I am using is a bit of an "overkill".
    # I am not sure if the implementation is correct.
    # You may sort the corners using simple logic - find top left, bottom right, and match the other two points.
    ############################################################################
    # Find the center of the contour
    # https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = M['m10']/M['m00']
    cy = M['m01']/M['m00']
    center_xy = np.array([cx, cy])

    cbox = box - center_xy  # Subtract the center from each corner

    # For a square the angles of the corners are:
    # -135   -45
    #
    #
    # 135     45
    ang = np.arctan2(cbox[:,1], cbox[:,0]) * 180 / np.pi  # Compute the angles from the center to each corner

    # Sort the corners of box counterclockwise (sort box elements according the order of ang).
    box = box[ang.argsort()]
    ############################################################################

    # Reorder points: top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right
    coor = np.float32([box[0], box[1], box[3], box[2]])

    return coor


input_image2 = cv2.imread("card_in_polygon_format.jpeg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as Grayscale
input_image2 = cv2.threshold(input_image2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Convert to binary image (just in case...)

# orig_im_coor = np.float32([[640, 184], [1002, 409], [211, 625], [589, 940]])

# Find the corners of the card, and sort them
orig_im_coor = find_corners(input_image2)

height, width = 450, 350
new_image_coor =  np.float32([[0, 0], [width, 0], [0, height], [width, height]])

P = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(orig_im_coor, new_image_coor)

perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(input_image2, P, (width, height))
cv2.imshow("Perspective transformation", perspective)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Quadrangle fitting (not most accurate):
[image]

Comment: Will it works for every type of images because if i pass the mask of image which is in polygon format , then it is not properly showing . I have to make the code global which should works for every type of images (any variation , any shape) as I have edited my post and added a image

Comment: Please don't change your question after getting answered. My answer applies your original question (please revert the edit). I recommend you first try solving it yourself, then you may post a new question - give a reference to the current post. Don't ask for something too general like "should works for every type of images". You are never get an answer if your are asking too much.

Comment: Deleted , No worries and Thanks for your answer ,

Comment: Can you please suggest the solution for this issue , I am trying but not working , Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224684/indexerror-index-3-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-3-while-giving-origina

Comment: I have posted an answer. Next time, when you are posting a followed up question, please add a link to the original post - it helps seeing the bigger picture.

Comment: Sure , I will take care of it next time .