# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3 while giving original image (color image)?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to apply the perspective information for unshearing the image using open cv . I had converted the image to black and white and then passes it to the model which is working fine . It is displaying the white mask which is actually the output . How can I display its original object of image instead of mask , it is throwing the index error.

**Code: **

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def find_corners(im):

    # Find contours in img.
    cnts = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # [-2] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).

    # Find the contour with the maximum area (required if there is more than one contour).
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    box = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)

    tmp_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.drawContours(tmp_im, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("tmp_im", tmp_im)

    box = np.squeeze(box).astype(np.float32)  


    # Sorting the points order is top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.
    # Find the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = M['m10']/M['m00']
    cy = M['m01']/M['m00']
    center_xy = np.array([cx, cy])

    cbox = box - center_xy  # Subtract the center from each corner
    
    ang = np.arctan2(cbox[:,1], cbox[:,0]) * 180 / np.pi  # Compute the angles from the center to each corner

    # Sort the corners of box counterclockwise (sort box elements according the order of ang).
    box = box[ang.argsort()]
    
    # Reorder points: top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right
    print('bbox',box)
    coor = np.float32([box[0], box[1], box[3], box[2]])
  

    return coor


input_image2 = cv2.imread("/home/hamza/Desktop/cards/card2.jpeg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as Grayscale
input_image2 = cv2.threshold(input_image2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Convert to binary image (just in case...)

# Find the corners of the card, and sort them
orig_im_coor = find_corners(input_image2)

height, width = 450, 350
new_image_coor =  np.float32([[0, 0], [width, 0], [0, height], [width, height]])

P = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(orig_im_coor, new_image_coor)

perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(input_image2, P, (width, height))
cv2.imshow("Perspective transformation", perspective)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Original Image**

**[image: original image]**

**Black and white image**

[image: binary image]

**Expected Output:**
The output I am getting is white mask from code which is fine but I want to take the image of that particular mask . How can I access it ?

If it is not possible using this approach , How can I do it from some other approach ?

**Edit 1:**
Code returning the output after unshearing the image as shown below in the image  , I have to put that particular mask on that output image which I give it as a input of mask from that specified image

**Code returning output now .  Below Output image is white please press on the image it will display you otherwise background is also white and it will not proper display you   :**
[image: output_image]

Comment: Could you please give some example of your input and expected output? Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is applying the transformation `cv2.warpPerspective` on the original image, instead of the black and white image.

- Read the "original image":

```python
    original_image = cv2.imread("original_image.jpg")
```

- Compute `orig_im_coor` and `P` as before.
- Apply the transformation on `original_image`:

```python
    perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(original_image, P, (width, height))
```

---

There is one more recommended stage:
Instead of manually setting height and width: `height, width = 450, 350`, it's recommended to compute the height and width.

Assuming the `orig_im_coor` coordinates are accurate enough, we can compute `height`, `width` according to the coordinates:

- Width is approximately the distance from top-left to top-right.
- Height is approximately the distance from top-left to bottom-left.

Computing the Euclidian distance is simple: sqrt(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>).
As a shortcut we can use `np.linalg.norm(a-b)` as described in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy):

```python
width = round(np.linalg.norm(orig_im_coor[0] - orig_im_coor[1]))  # Assume width is the distance from top-left to top-right
height = round(np.linalg.norm(orig_im_coor[0] - orig_im_coor[2]))  # Assume height is the distance from top-left to bottom-left
```

---

Here is the complete code:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np


def find_corners(im):
    """ 
    Find "card" corners in a binary image.
    Return a list of points in the following format: [[640, 184], [1002, 409], [211, 625], [589, 940]] 
    The points order is top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right.
    """

    # Better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127342/detect-card-minarea-quadrilateral-from-contour-opencv

    # Find contours in img.
    cnts = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # [-2] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).

    # Find the contour with the maximum area (required if there is more than one contour).
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138000/fit-quadrilateral-tetragon-to-a-blob
    epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    box = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)

    # Draw box for testing
    #tmp_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    #cv2.drawContours(tmp_im, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    #cv2.imshow("tmp_im", tmp_im)

    box = np.squeeze(box).astype(np.float32)  # Remove redundant dimensions


    # Sorting the points order is top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.
    # Note: 
    # The method I am using is a bit of an "overkill".
    # I am not sure if the implementation is correct.
    # You may sort the corners using simple logic - find top left, bottom right, and match the other two points.
    ############################################################################
    # Find the center of the contour
    # https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = M['m10']/M['m00']
    cy = M['m01']/M['m00']
    center_xy = np.array([cx, cy])

    cbox = box - center_xy  # Subtract the center from each corner

    # For a square the angles of the corners are:
    # -135   -45
    #
    #
    # 135     45
    ang = np.arctan2(cbox[:,1], cbox[:,0]) * 180 / np.pi  # Compute the angles from the center to each corner

    # Sort the corners of box counterclockwise (sort box elements according the order of ang).
    box = box[ang.argsort()]
    ############################################################################

    # Reorder points: top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right
    coor = np.float32([box[0], box[1], box[3], box[2]])

    return coor

original_image = cv2.imread("original_image.jpg")  # Read the original image

bw_mask = cv2.imread("black_and_white_mask.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as Grayscale
bw_mask = cv2.threshold(bw_mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Convert to binary image (just in case...)

# Find the corners of the mask, and sort them
orig_im_coor = find_corners(bw_mask)

# Compute width and height of the destination image according to orig_im_coor
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy
width = round(np.linalg.norm(orig_im_coor[0] - orig_im_coor[1]))  # Assume width is the distance from top-left to top-right
height = round(np.linalg.norm(orig_im_coor[0] - orig_im_coor[2]))  # Assume height is the distance from top-left to bottom-left

#height, width = 450, 350
new_image_coor =  np.float32([[0, 0], [width, 0], [0, height], [width, height]])

P = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(orig_im_coor, new_image_coor)

#perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(input_image2, P, (width, height))

# Apply the perspective transform on the original_image
perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(original_image, P, (width, height))

cv2.imshow("Perspective transformation", perspective)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

---

### Update:

**Cropping the masked region without warping.**

Here is an example for cropping without warping:

```python
original_image = cv2.imread("original_image.jpg")  # Read the original image

bw_mask = cv2.imread("black_and_white_mask.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as Grayscale
bw_mask = cv2.threshold(bw_mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Convert to binary image (just in case...)

# Find the corners of the mask, and sort them
orig_im_coor = find_corners(bw_mask)

# Mask the background - place zeros where mask is zero
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(original_image, original_image, mask=bw_mask)

# The corners are the minimum and maximum of orig_im_coor
x0 = int(round(orig_im_coor[:, 0].min()))
y0 = int(round(orig_im_coor[:, 1].min()))
x1 = int(round(orig_im_coor[:, 0].max()))
y1 = int(round(orig_im_coor[:, 1].max()))
cropped_masked_image = masked_image[y0:y1+1, x0:x1+1, :].copy()  # Crop area from top-left to bottom-right

# Show the results:
cv2.imshow('masked_image', masked_image)
cv2.imshow('cropped_masked_image', cropped_masked_image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Results:

`masked_image`:
[image]

`cropped_masked_image`:
[image]

Comment: Your answer is fine , This is the thing I am also looking for from past 4 days , but Can't we make that output from black and white mask instead of passing original image ?

Comment: Sure... pass the black and white image as an input and get a white image. Note that the black and white image is used all along, and only the final transformation applies the original image.

Comment: No , I am saying that if I pass black and white image , Will I get output of original mask as you have showed the picture in your answer ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The transformed original mask is a transformed white mask.

Comment: Yes , exactly I am also saying this that , instead of getting transformed white mask from the black and white image as a input , Can we get transformed original object (color etc ) from black and white mask ?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. We are getting the transformed original color object according to the black and white mask.

Comment: @Rotem , as you have suggested me to not take out the height and width manually , what is the reason behind it , and after applying perspective transformation , there is blur blur type of image (after converting) , pic is not too clear as you can see in the output of card

Comment: @Rotem No issue , I got point some how . Can you please just answer one thing that How you obtain color object according to black and white mask , which technique you used . I am confused with some part of code !

Comment: I updated my post, showing how to crop the masked region without warping. Is that what you have meant? You can also use `cv2.boundingRect` as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html). You don't need to find the corners...