# Rotated image when using "findHomography" and "warpPerspective"

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am currently developing an ALPR system. To detect the plate first I am using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020751/how-to-detect-rectangle-from-houghlines-transform-in-opencv-java).

**The problem** comes with certain images. After using *findHomography* and *warpPerspective* it gives me the plate image rotated.

#### This is the original image that gives me issues.

[image]

#### This is the detected plate contour

[image]

#### And this is the warped image

[image]

As you can see it is rotated 90 degrees. In other examples the detection works amazing.

The specific piece of code

```
cv::Mat warpped_plate( PLATE_HEIGHT, PLATE_WIDTH, CV_8UC3 );
vector< cv::Point> real_plate_polygons;
real_plate_polygons = {cv::Point(PLATE_WIDTH, PLATE_HEIGHT), cv::Point(0, PLATE_HEIGHT), cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Point(PLATE_WIDTH, 0)};
cv::Mat homography = cv::findHomography( plate_polygons, real_plate_polygons );
cv::warpPerspective(source_img, warpped_plate, homography, cv::Size(PLATE_WIDTH, PLATE_HEIGHT));
```

Where *plate_polygons* contains the four points of the plate (and are correct, because were used to draw the white box in the mask).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then, `plate_polygon` is obviously in the wrong order. Cycle the entries to achieve the corner order you have in `real_plate_polygons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nico mentioned, the problem was with the order of the points in the *plate_polygon*. The algorithm generating them was not consistent on the start point (in my case, starting from lower).