# Find rectangular object quality with perspective

Tags: c++, opencv, rectangles, perspective, opencv-solvepnp

I get image from a camera (calibrated and without lens distortions) and I need to detect a rectangular object. Markers are a good example. For markers I check corner count, min size, board contrast and convexity. I had an idea on how to improve this in cases where there is large amount of false rectangles.
Here is an example image:

[image]

Normally all of these are valid, because without knowing anything about camera we cannot determine if perspective allows these kinds of shapes. I know the size (or at least the ratio) of the rectangle in real-life. So I had an idea that I should be able to disregard many of these shapes just by reprojecting them and checking for error.
Like if I use solvePnPRansac it would not be able to converge if the shape is not possible. If it doesn't converge I just disregard it. Sadly, none of the OpenCV solve functions allow checking me for error or convergence. I actually need some ratio or quality, because it is possible that some of the rectangles overlap. For example my object finder identifies these rectangles:

[image: overlap image]

One of the three is actually correct, or at least "the best". But I need some way to know which one it is. I cannot use things like line lengths because of the camera perspective. So I just thought I could solve and see which has the smallest error.

There are no lens distortions in the image, but even if there were solvePnP usually allows passing D to it as well.
Is this even possible or am I missing something?
I guess I could try hacking around solvePnPRansac just to return convergence, but maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: This is really cool question, but I doubt it fits stack exchange format because it's just a little bit too theoretical and kinda involves discussion. You should really try some CV forums to talk about the issue with other people.

Comment: You can calculate the aspect ratio of a projected rectangle (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285229/counting-aspect-ratio-of-perspective-transform-destination-image/38402378#38402378 ). If you already know the aspect ratio, you could: estimate the aspect ration based on the corners, then checks if it matches the ratio you know.

Comment: Tomáš Zato - I did want to post it in answers.opencv.org, but they didn't allow me to post pictures (or link to them) because I haven't posted much there before. I have to up my karma.

Comment: y300, I'll try that. I do have camera focal distance, because of the calibration though. So I guess it should give me more precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I can do something like what is done during calibration with a grid. I can calculate the reprojection error. So first I solve to get the transformation matrix. Then I transform the points in 3D using the transformation matrix and afterwards use projectPoints to project them back in 2D. Then I check distance between original 2D points and the projected 2D points. This can then be used for quality. Objects that are not possible often have 100 pixels or more reprojection error in my images, but possible objects have less than 20px. So I just did a 25 pixel cutoff and it seems to work fine.

Note that more transformations are possible than I though. In my original image maybe two are not possible with my current camera, but it still did reject a lot of fakes.

If nobody else has some ideas I will accept this as answer.

Here is some code for the method I use:

```
  //This is the object in 3D
  double width = 50.0; //Object is 50mm wide
  double height = 30.0; //Object is 30mm tall
  cv::Mat object_points(4,3,CV_64FC1);
  object_points.at<double>(0,0)=0;
  object_points.at<double>(0,1)=0;
  object_points.at<double>(0,2)=0;
  object_points.at<double>(1,0)=width;
  object_points.at<double>(1,1)=0;
  object_points.at<double>(1,2)=0;
  object_points.at<double>(2,0)=width;
  object_points.at<double>(2,1)=height;
  object_points.at<double>(2,2)=0;
  object_points.at<double>(3,0)=0;
  object_points.at<double>(3,1)=height;
  object_points.at<double>(3,2)=0;

  //Check all rectangles for error
  cv::Mat image_points(4,2,CV_64FC1);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rectangles_to_test.size(); i++) {
    // Get rectangle points
    for (size_t c = 0; c < 4; ++c) {
      image_points.at<double>(c,0) = (rectangles_to_test[i].points[c].x);
      image_points.at<double>(c,1) = (rectangles_to_test[i].points[c].y);
    }

    // Calculate transformation matrix
    cv::Mat rvec, tvec;
    cv::solvePnP(object_points, image_points, M1, D1, rvec, tvec);

    cv::Mat rotation; 
    Matrix4<double> transform;
    transform.init_identity();
    cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rotation);

    for(size_t row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
      for(size_t col = 0; col < 3; ++col) {
        transform.set(row, col, rotation.at<double>(row, col));
      }
      transform.set(row, 3, tvec.at<double>(row, 0));
    }

    // Calculate projection
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> p3(4);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> p2;
    Vector4<double> p = transform * Vector4<double>(0, 0, 0, 1);
    p3[0] = cv::Point3f((float)p.x, (float)p.y, (float)p.z);
    p = transform * Vector4<double>(width, 0, 0, 1);
    p3[1] = cv::Point3f((float)p.x, (float)p.y, (float)p.z); 
    p = transform * Vector4<double>(width, height, 0, 1);
    p3[2] = cv::Point3f((float)p.x, (float)p.y, (float)p.z); 
    p = transform * Vector4<double>(0, height, 0, 1);
    p3[3] = cv::Point3f((float)p.x, (float)p.y, (float)p.z); 

    cv::projectPoints(p3, cv::Mat::zeros(1, 3, CV_64FC1), cv::Mat::zeros(1, 3, CV_64FC1), M1, D1, p2);

    // Calculate reprojection error
    rectangles_to_test[i].reprojection_error = 0.0;
    for (size_t c = 0; c < 4; ++c) {
      double dx = p2[c].x - rectangles_to_test[i].points[c].x;
      double dy = p2[c].y - rectangles_to_test[i].points[c].y;
      rectangles_to_test[i].reprojection_error += std::sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    }
    if (rectangles_to_test[i].reprojection_error > reprojection_error_threshold) {
      //rectangle is no good
    }
  }
```