# Perspective transform with whole image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, perspective

So I have four points in an array `A`, denoting the corners of a rectangular object (but not a rectangle when projected onto the image plane). I know the size of the rectangle, so I can calculate the perspective transform with

```
cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(four_corners, np.array([[0, 0], [0, height], [width, height], [width, 0], dtype=np.float32))
```

Then I can transform the image with `cv2.warpPerspective`.

The problem (which can be demonstrated by another people's question [Counting aspect ratio of Perspective Transform destination image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285229/counting-aspect-ratio-of-perspective-transform-destination-image)) is that the warped result is cropped. Only the region inside the four corners are in the final image, while I want the whole original image to be warped into the final result.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: did you find a way for it?